Python Class to run the equation but can't understand one of def ()
I'm self-learning python and it teaches concept of "Class" from https://python-programming.quantecon.org/python_oop.html
The below is full codes.
I can understand that

def h() is the one calculating the equation (the image at the bottom has equation)
def update() is the one calculating t and t+1
def denerate_sequecence() is the one append all returns.

But my question is: anybody can explain what def steady_state() is?
I can't find where this computing is originated from.
(((s * z) / (n + δ))**(1 / (1 - α))
Am I lacking of understanding this equation, or understanding how class and methods are interacting?
class Solow:
    r"""
    Implements the Solow growth model with the update rule

        k_{t+1} = [(s z k^α_t) + (1 - δ)k_t] /(1 + n)

    """
    def __init__(self, n=0.05,  # population growth rate
                       s=0.25,  # savings rate
                       δ=0.1,   # depreciation rate
                       α=0.3,   # share of labor
                       z=2.0,   # productivity
                       k=1.0):  # current capital stock

        self.n, self.s, self.δ, self.α, self.z = n, s, δ, α, z
        self.k = k

    def h(self):
        "Evaluate the h function"
        # Unpack parameters (get rid of self to simplify notation)
        n, s, δ, α, z = self.n, self.s, self.δ, self.α, self.z
        # Apply the update rule
        return (s * z * self.k**α + (1 - δ) * self.k) / (1 + n)

    def update(self):
        "Update the current state (i.e., the capital stock)."
        self.k =  self.h()

    def steady_state(self):
        "Compute the steady state value of capital."
        # Unpack parameters (get rid of self to simplify notation)
        n, s, δ, α, z = self.n, self.s, self.δ, self.α, self.z
        # Compute and return steady state
        return ((s * z) / (n + δ))**(1 / (1 - α))

    def generate_sequence(self, t):
        "Generate and return a time series of length t"
        path = []
        for i in range(t):
            path.append(self.k)
            self.update()
        return path 



The last line of the quoted text says what steady state is. That function seems to be calculating that k.

Just a little bit lower on the page than your image, it fully describes steady state and even gives you a plot to illustrate it. Steady state appears to be the non-normalized point of convergence between 2 pieces of data that trend toward one another (roughly).

This appears to be a math question, and not a programming question.

The code provided may not be correct. You are missing an explanation of how the formula was derived. solow.steady_state() essentially solves for k when k_t=k_t+1.
In the provided formula, we set all these k and solve for k:
k = ( sz(k**a) + (1 - δ)k ) / (1 + n)
Swap k and (1 + n):
1+n = ( sz(k**a) + (1 - δ)k ) / k
Simplify expression on the right:
1+n =  sz(k**a)/k + 1 - δ
Again:
1+n =  sz(k**(a-1)) + 1 - δ
Cancel the ones and move δ:
n + δ=  sz(k**(a-1))
Move sz over:
(n + δ) / sz =  k**(a-1)
From here, remove the exponent:
((n + δ) / sz)**(1 / (1 - α)) = k
The expression in the code is essentially similar:
((sz) / (n + δ))**(1 / (1 - α) = k
I do not know why this code has the expressions flipped from how I solved it, but if it works, I assume there is some reason I am not see that reversing those two terms works. Perhaps it is computing 1/k instead of k directly, which would be the best explanation if it produces the desired results. Or the other possibility is the k always equals 1/k for some logical reason in this equation.

Since k = k_t = k_t+1 at equilibrium, the steady state solution is simply the result of solving for k in equation 8.1 (substituting k_t and k_t+1 with k). The class provides the option to directly produce this steady state solution with the  steady_state method. I would expect after many updates, Solow.h() would approach Solow.steady_state().
Note, in this class, the steady_state def isn't interacting with the other methods, it's simply another method that the class can call.
